# Symbol for "Unicode mess"

Tags: unicode

I'm looking for a symbol which meaning is "things that should not be in Unicode".

Does such Unicode character exist (yet)? If yes, what's the codepoint? If not, how do I propose for it?

Comment: What do you mean? How could a character mean that phrase? What do you mean by “Unicode mess”?

Comment: Can you provide an example of some "things that should not be in Unicode"?

Comment: Is this the same question as the one that can never be asked?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper man in business suit levitating? woman with bunny ears?

Comment: @Ron: Ok, so it's more about things that *are* not in Unicode? (Given that Unicode defines all kinds of surprising symbols, I'd refrain from claiming those two examples *should not* be in Unicode.)

Answer (score 3):

The [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (U+FFFD) �](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) should be used for characters that can't be represented. From the link:

> used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode